# Gmail API Quota Limit Exceeded When Sending Too Many Emails

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I am creating email automation platform using gmail api and nodejs. It works fine unless the email list contain >100 emails.

When i try to send the emails i am getting this error

> Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute per user'  of service 'gmail.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:xxxxxxxxxxxxx'.

To send the email I am using the following method

```
const r = await gmail.users.messages.send({
  auth, // coming from google oauth client
  userId: "me",
  requestBody: {
    raw: makeEmailBody( // function to create base64 email body with necessary headers
      thread.send_to,
      {
        address: user.from_email,
        name: user.from_name,
      },
      subject,
      template,
      thread.id
    ),
  },
});
```

Comment: could you check your quotas? under `GCP` console on Gmail API -> Quotas.

Comment: Gmail has limits on how many you can send at a time. This is why other offerings exist.

Comment: I believe you can adjust this `100` limit to a `1000`

Comment: "I am creating email automation platform using gmail api and nodejs."  Well, there's your problem!  You can't use Gmail in this way.

Comment: @Brad but [YAMM](https://yet-another-mail-merge.com/) tool is doing the same. Why google ain't blocking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Information about [Usage limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota)

> Per user rate limit   250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows short bursts).

and

> Method--------------------------Quota Units
>
> messages.send-----------------100

In other words, sending 100 emails corresponds to using 10 000 quota units, but you are only allowed to use 250 quota units per second.

This means that you need to slow down your code execution to avoid running into quota issues.

This can be done with an **Exponential Backoff logarithm**, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/handle-errors#exponential-backoff).

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I have now found a way to schedule the 2 emails per second <3